# How do I invite a friend to like my page?

Tags: facebook

I have found answers to this but they don't work. I want to invite my friends to like my band page.

If I am on the band page and try to *Build an audience*, it only gives me options to do this via email. If I am on my personal page I see no option for *Build an audience*.

I am obviously the administrator to my own page I assume.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to share your band page while viewing it from your personal page.

[image]

There also should have a “Invite Your Friends to Like This Page” on the band page. You should be able to invite your friends through that functionality.

[image]